concourse fly cli issue on Mac: could not reach the Concourse server called
I have no permission on sudo or update Security&Privacy Setting. Below are my step:

Downloaded needed version 6.7.1.

chmod +x fly

mv fly ~/bin

export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

source ~/.zshrc

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/bin/fly


"fly --version" shows correct version. But I can't connect to server. I can access server in browser!
fly -t main login --concourse-url 'https://ci.xxx.com' --team-name 'my-team'

logging in to team 'my-team'

could not reach the Concourse server called main:

    Get https://ci.xxx,com/api/v1/info: dial tcp: i/o timeout

is the targeted Concourse running? better go catch it lol


I tried another way:
brew install --cask fly
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /opt/homebrew/bin/fly

It gets the latest version and prompts for login, and I was able to login. But it gives error:
fly version (7.12.0) is out of sync with the target (6.7.1). to sync up, run the following:

    fly -t main sync

I ignored the warning and run the command, it refused to connect
cowardly refusing to run due to significant version discrepancy

So I run "fly -t main sync" to sync with server vision 6.7.1
Then I got this lol message again!
could not reach the Concourse server called main:

    Get https://ci.xxx,com/api/v1/info: dial tcp: i/o timeout

is the targeted Concourse running? better go catch it lol

Please suggest. Thanks!
